# About Dirac equation in curved spacetime (spherical)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, metric-tensor, dirac-equation

I would like to ask you about the separation of variables of the Dirac equation in curved space-time. The metric is given by  $$ds^{2}=-dt^{2}+dr^{2}+r^{2}d\theta^{2}+\alpha^{2}r^{2}\sin^{2}\theta d\phi^{2},$$ where $\alpha$ is a positive constant. The Dirac equation(a part of) is given by $$i \gamma^{\mu}(x)(\partial_\mu+\Gamma_{\mu}(x))\psi(x)=0$$ where $\Gamma_{\mu}(x)$ is spinor affine connections and $\gamma^{\mu}$ are the general Dirac matrices. If we define the tetrad base as $$e^{\mu}_{(a)}=\left(
                 \begin{array}{cccc}
                   1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                   0 & \sin\theta \cos\phi &\sin\theta \sin\phi & \cos\theta \\
                   0 & \frac{\cos\theta \cos\phi }{r}&\frac{ \cos\theta \sin\phi}{r} & -\frac{\sin \theta}{r} \\
                   0 & -\frac{\sin\phi}{\alpha r \sin\theta} & \frac{\cos\phi}{\alpha r \sin\theta}& 0\\
                 \end{array}
               \right)
,$$ using the tetrad base we obtain(But I cannot!):

> Blockquote

$\gamma^{\mu}(x)\Gamma^{\mu}(x)=\frac{1}{2r}(1-\frac{1}{\alpha})\csc\theta(\gamma^{(1)}\cos\phi+\gamma^{(2)}\sin\phi)$

> Blockquote

. Here, $\gamma^{(a)}$ are flat Dirac matrices. Moreover, $$\gamma^{\mu}(x)\Gamma^{\mu}(x)=\frac{1}{2}\gamma^{(a)}[(\partial_{\mu}e_{(a)}^{\mu}(x)+e_{(a)}^{\rho}(x)\Gamma^{\mu}_{\rho \mu})+i\gamma^{(5)}\varepsilon_{(a)(b)(c)(d)}e^{(b)\mu}e^{(c)\nu}\partial_{\mu}e^{(d)}_{\nu}]$$

Now my question is: how one can obtain $\gamma^{\mu}(x)\Gamma^{\mu}(x)$ expansion above, which is $$\gamma^{\mu}(x)\Gamma^{\mu}(x)=\frac{1}{2r}(1-\frac{1}{\alpha})\csc\theta(\gamma^{(1)}\cos\phi+\gamma^{(2)}\sin\phi),$$ because I couldn't obtain it. I'm not used to this notation :(